# How do I insert multilines in Perl regexps?

Tags: perl

I am using regexps in order to move blocks of text but it only removes single lines - what should I include in order to remove multiple lines?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for `/<!--\[perl\](.*?)-->/s`

Use option switch `/s`

It treats string as a single line.

"." (dot) will match any character at all, including newline.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that often trip people up when trying to make regexes work across multiple lines.

The first is the fact that a dot in a regex doesn't match a newline unless you use the `/s` option on your `m//` or `s///` operator.

The second is that if you're processing a text file a line at a time (perhaps with `while (<$filehandle>) { ... }`) then each time round the loop you only have a single line of text to match against. You'll need to read the whole file in at once (perhaps using `$text = do { local $/; <$filehandle>};`).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

{
    local $/ = '-->';
    while (my $chunk = <DATA>) {
        $chunk =~ s/<!-- \[perl\] (.*) --> \z//sx;
        print $chunk;
    }
}

__DATA__
<!--[perl]

my $x = 5;
my $y = 3;
say $x + $y

-->

<!--[not]

const char *s = "This is not Perl ;-)";

-->
```

By judiciously altering the [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24RS), you can ensure that every chunk you read ends with the string `"-->"`. Then, it's a matter of ensuring `.` can match line endings by supplying the `/s` flag to your substitution operator.

Output:

```
<!--[not]

const char *s = "This is not Perl ;-)";

-->
```

You can also remove leading/trailing space from the chunks if that matters.